# Not able to change the value of instance in python

Tags: python, instance

I am trying to use the MIME and send the email using the following code. But the python is not able to change the value of the msg['Subject']. What I am doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Thanks

```
msg = MIMEText('MAIL from my python programme')
msg['Subject'] = 'Testing '
msg['From'] = USERNAME
msg['To'] = MAILTO

test_var=1

if(test_var):
    msg['Subject'] = 'Test variable is 1'
else:
    msg['Subject'] = 'Test variable is 0'

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
server.starttls()
server.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
server.login(USERNAME,PASSWORD)
server.sendmail(USERNAME, MAILTO, msg.as_string())
server.quit()
print "sending email"
```

Comment: *"But the python is not able to change the value"* — how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: WHat error are you getting? And please answer @ErikAllik's comment too...

Comment: Because when I send the email, I get the subject 'Testing' rather than the one I want like 'Test variable is 1/0'.

Answer (score 2):

From what I can tell, you have to delete the `Subject` field (or any other) before you replace it. Otherwise, it just appends more subjects - which might be ignored, looking like the value doesn't change.

```
test_var=1

del msg['Subject']
if(test_var):
    msg['Subject'] = 'Test variable is 1'
else:
    msg['Subject'] = 'Test variable is 0'
```

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense. Do you know which syntax is better either yours del msg['Subject'] or msg.__delitems__.('Subject')?

Comment: you don't even need to set it the first time at all.

Comment: @user3560452: They're functionally equivalent (`del msg['Subject']` actually just calls `msg.__delitem__('Subject')`), but using `del` is preferred where possible because it avoids using the private function `__delitem__`

Comment: @Erik But what if I again want to change the value. So even if I do not set it the first time, the issue will remain. And the solution provided by Mostly Harmless is needed.